# Search in Set collections

Tags: java, search, collections, set

I have a Role object in which there is a set of Rolenames, I want to make a check on whether the user has a particular role. Tell me how best to do it to be beautiful and concise.

Role.java

```
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @NaturalId
    @Column(length = 60)
    private RoleName name;
```

RoleName.java:

```
public enum RoleName {
    ROLE_ADMIN,
    ROLE_MANAGER,
    ROLE_CLIENT,
    ROLE_USER,
}
```

Now my search looks like this:

```
boolean isFind = false;
        for (Role role : user.getRoles()) {
            isFind = role.getName().equals(RoleName.ROLE_CLIENT);
            if (isFind) break;
        }
```

But I do not really like this way. Can you suggest a better option?

Comment: For the record: you can compare enums using ==.

Comment: What type is returned by `user.getRoles()`? If you can make it a `Set` (ideally an `EnumSet`) then the whole of your code collapses into `user.getRoles().contains(RoleName.ROLE_CLIENT)`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon `user.getRoles()` returned Set collections `Roles`

Comment: All collections have `contains()`, since it is from the Interface `Collection<E>`

Comment: @AndreyPopov - Perfect! Then just use `user.getRoles().contains(RoleName.ROLE_CLIENT)`.

Comment: without using `Java Streams` your code looks good. as an alternative you can use `iterator` but the code will be similar to provided

Comment: how `contains()` can be used? it will search for type `RoleName` in a collection of `Role`. the only way to do this is to overried the `equals` method in the `Role` class

Comment: True `contains()`, will test if `Role` contains the same `Role` object not the `RoleName`, as @Maxim said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use stream such as :

```
boolean isFind = 
    user.getRoles()
        .stream()
        .map(Role::getName)
        .anyMatch(n -> n == RoleName.ROLE_CLIENT);
```